# Ubuntu won't boot after plugging in wireless network card

Tags: 10.04, server, wireless, boot, pci

I plugged a Skyr@cer Pro PCI 154 into a Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS and tried to boot. It won't  get further that launching AppArmor, sometimes even not that far. Without the network card, everything works just fine.

Is there anything I need to do prior to installing new hardware? Please note that I have no access to the graphical interface.

Comment: This is likely a hardware conflict.  You need to review what interrupt, IRQ, and RAM settings are in use without (and with) this card installed.  You should be able to find this out in advanced BIOS settings.  Please also provide more details about server hardware (board, CPU, RAM).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried booting into a Single User mode to see what driver Ubuntu is trying to load for this card?

From GRUB Screen:
Select Kernel
press 'e' to edit and append `single` to the line

Once in the single user mode run:

```
lspci -vvv
```

and post the output.  Based on what I can see about this card the driver for it should be the Windows one using `ndiswrapper` but based on the CHIP on the card UBUNTU may try to select something else and that may be causing some problems.